# Max height and width with jquery resize

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, window-resize

I'm using the jquery resize to resize content on my webpage. It works, but I want that when the element reaches the desired height or width, it should stop resizing, how do I achieve this?

Here's the code:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    $(map).height(win.height() - 210);

    if($(window).height() == 300){
        $(map).css({
                    "height": "250px"
                    });
    }
});
```

I did an if statement but it still doesn't work, what's wrong with the code. Please advise me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Set the `maxHeight` of the resizable div

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#map").resizable({
      maxHeight: 300
    });
});
```

And then set the corresponding `div` to have a scroll bar on `overflow`

```
#map{
  overflow:scroll;
}
```

This would allow the `div` to always have a scroll bar and limit the user when resizing the corresponding `div`

source: [jQuery resizable API (max/min)](http://jqueryui.com/resizable/#max-min)

Comment: Just note, typo here, it should be integer (300, not 300px)

Answer (score 0):

You're saying if it = 300. Tthat is very specific, I would use `>= 300`

Comment: I just did >= 300, but it jumps to that height and it stays at that height, no matter how I resize the window after. I think the resize event stops running when it reaches that height of 300. All I want is when it reaches 300px height, a scrollbar should appear and the user can scroll up to see the rest of the content. Do you know how to that?